# Mouse requiring clicking twice in most cases, not sure why?

Tags: mouse

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 using an Apple Magic Mouse (version 1) and I'm finding that I have to click twice to select things quiet often. But I can't establish a pattern to get it to happen all the time. When it does happen it seems to do it many times consecutively.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Replace the mouse (and it's an hardware problem therefore off topic here).

Comment: I concur that this sounds like a hardware issue. There may be some dirt in the actual electrical button underneath the casing. Also, the small metal sheet that’s used in the button to provide tactile feedback wears out over time with use. Either bend it back into shape, replace the button (if you can find a replacement part and know how to solder), or replace the entire mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue turned out to be that Ubuntu's drivers for the Magic Mouse (hid_magicmouse I think?) introduce a middle button region on the Magic Mouse. When disabled this acts as a dead zone. I discovered that my finger was sitting right on the edge of the left click region and the right click region so my first click was often in the middle while my second click was just slightly more to the left and hence it worked.

Although I didn't try this, I theorize you could reassign the middle region to behave as left click as well.

Thank you for your feedback guys.